# What is Edge Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What does "Edge Rails" mean? I found some hints on the interweb, but it's not clear, does it mean the latest Rails or Rails 2.2 or what?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Edge rails is the [Rails master branch](http://github.com/rails/rails/commits/). It means everything up to the very newest commit.

Comment: It is also the name of a blog which describes the changes in the newest commits: http://www.edgerails.info/ :)

Answer (score 6):

It means the latest Rails. The newest :)

Comment: But not the latest released version, it is the latest unreleased version.

Answer (score 0):

The newest one.

Edge rails may contain lots of bugs, so use it carefully.

Comment: At the moment, your statement is wrong. Modern Rails Edge version is very stable. It doesn't contain untested code. I've used it for a year. It's useful if you need the last  features.

Answer (score 0):

It's the latest rails commit and everything in this commit is very much new and its not guaranteed to be stable!
Its a funride and someone might enjoy and someone might not!