# When does Rails 5.2 reach end of life?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Does anyone know when Rails 5.2 reaches end of life? Is there a central place where end of life dates for Rails are documented?

Comment: While not an authoritative resource, the wikipedia tracks Rails versions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails

Answer (score 1):

Rails don't do long term support of old versions. They only release security path.
You can get a better idea of how this work here:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html

It is important to emphasize that you have to keep updating the gem of rails to avoid incompatibilities in the future, see the case of the update of Github in rails 3 to version rails 6

https://github.blog/2018-09-28-upgrading-github-from-rails-3-2-to-5-2/
https://github.blog/2019-09-09-running-github-on-rails-6-0/

Answer (score 1):

> Rails 5.2.Z is included in the list of supported series until June 1st 2022.

You can find the central place where end of life dates for Rails are documented at https://endoflife.date/rails
or at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe Rails 6 is still "Edge" (unreleased) and Rails 5 is the latest released version. (See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856228/what-is-edge-rails) for definitions.) As such, I believe there is no EOL date for Rails 5.

I believe you can find, essentially, EOL information by looking at the latest release notes, as discussed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050213/ruby-on-rails-4-2-end-of-life).

Comment: Rails 6 was released [2019-08-15](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2019/8/15/Rails-6-0-final-release/).